# bearing if it was not invented at all

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Can anyone here be able to explain with figures , why there was a need of bearing with shaft . What would be the case if bearing was not invented at all ?

Comment: Nazi Germany had a their ball-bearing factories bombed. They just used alternatives until the factory were functional again. Straight from the mouth of one of the military personnel. I have trouble thinking of things where you actually NEED ball bearing. Often it's just that if you don't use them you have more wear and lower performance.

Comment: Well, maybe you need them for things like get engines which spin at 10,000RPM+ since fluid bearings can't be used there. I am not sure if Uranium centrifuges which spin at 100,000RPM even use ball bearings. They might use fluid bearings. Those are two things where the wear would result in catastrophic damage or wear so quickly that they would not be practical.

Comment: Friction affects all moving surfaces in contact. Damage will occur and varies with speed, load etc Even things that have low rotational speeds wear, like door latch pins sliding into catches wear out over time.

Comment: By bearing are you referring to ball bearings? There are other kinds of bearings too.

Answer (score 1):

Bearings convert the friction between the shaft and hub into a rolling mechanism.

- It reduces the friction to almost zero. Hence freeing the enrgy used to fight the friction to go to better use.
- It thus generates much less damaging heat and wear and tear. Or the oxidation of lubricant. A bicycle lasts many generations of a family owing to its bearings.
- It can be designed to take a transversal or angled load.
- It can be made of high-quality material, which would be impractical if the entire shaft were to be upgraded.

.

[image: bicyle]

Answer (score 0):

Prior to ball bearings, etc., "journal" or "plain" bearings were a common solution for all sorts of applications including railway rolling stock. Traditionally these were made of a bronze bushing to support a steel shaft. A good lubrication routine is required to minimise wear and heating. (See railway "hot box" detection.)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_bearing) has a good article.

More recently high quality plastic bearings such as those made by [Igus](https://www.igus.com/info/spherical-bearings) are common in certain industrial applications.

Comment: a journal bearing is a bearing

Comment: @TigerGuy, true and that has a bearing on the subject. The question is a rather vague or naive.

Answer (score 0):

*** As soon as people had a need for rotating devices, a bearing was needed.

Ancient wood on wood bearings for carts give both the support and shaft short lives.  As soon as technology permitted, people began using devices to reduce friction.  If bearings didn't exist, most devices with rotating parts would be stuck in pre-industrial times.

Comment: First thing they used was animal fat as grease - "technology"...